# How can I make strftime show year as in 2022 instead of 22? Is there a way?

Tags: c

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
struct tm* timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
strftime(arr, sizeof(arr)-1 , "%d/%m/%y", timeinfo);
puts(arr);
```

The output is 15/9/22, I want it 15/9/2022.I need it to be stored in a char array

Answer (score 3):

Just use `%Y` instead of lowercase y.  Clear in documentation.

```
strftime(arr, sizeof(arr)-1 , "%d/%m/%Y", timeinfo);
```

Comment: That didn't work, nothing was printed on the console. I think it works only in python not c.

Comment: please show your exact code -- here is a "C" reference page  https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: If your code looks like the example -- please show me the decl of the arr varable.

Comment: No it is not, actually it is a function in a class. the class contains a struct which contains a character array of size 10. the arr is nameofthestruct->arr.

Comment: @MariamAhmedElsendiony Grinch! `strlen( "25/12/2022" )` > 10 (when you consider the '\0')... You better fix that before Santa finds out! :-)

Comment: Should have pointed out that `strftime()` already knows to allow for the '\0' (like `fgets( )`), and the "sizeof arr -1" was incorrect usage

Answer (score 3):

Based on additional information supplied by the OP under @Hogan's answer, here is the fix:

Change:

```
strftime(arr, sizeof(arr)-1 , "%d/%m/%y", timeinfo);
```

to

```
strftime( arr, sizeof arr, "%d/%m/%Y", timeinfo );
```

The 'Y' will give a 4 digit year and the OP has stated that the destination array is "minimal" for "dd/mm/yyyy" (11 bytes only) with nothing to spare. By subtracting 1 in the parameter list, `strftime()` did the best that it could.

Like `fgets( )` and unlike the dangerous `strncat( )`, one uses this function (passing the full buffer size) safe in the knowledge that the function "knows" it is returning a "null terminated string".

EDIT: Credit where credit is due. @Hogan asked the "pivotal" question that led to this answer.